# How can I prove this property?

Tags: fourier-analysis

I need some help... I am asked to prove the following property of the Fourier transform, when $F[f(x)]=\widetilde{f}(x)$, where $F[f(x)]$ is the Fourier transform of $f(x)$:

> $$F[ \widetilde{f}(x) ]= \frac{f(-k)}{2 \pi}$$

We know that: $F[ \widetilde{f}(x) ]=\int_{- \infty}^{+ \infty}{ \widetilde{f}(x) e^{-i k x}}dx$.

But how can I prove this? I got stuck.. :/ Could you give me a hint?

Comment: Compare the formulas of the forward and reverse transform. They are *very* similar!

Comment: @fgp When I start with $F[ \widetilde{f}(x) ]=\int_{- \infty}^{+ \infty}{ \widetilde{f}(x) e^{-i k x}}dx$, what can I replace at $ \widetilde{f}(x)$??

Comment: What you are doing is finding the fourier transform $\tilde f$ of the function $f$, and then applying the fourier transform to $\tilde f$ *again*. If you applied the *reverse* transform the second time, you'd obviously get back to $f$. So write down both $F[\tilde f]$ and $F^{-1}[\tilde f] = f$ and compare...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \bar {f}(x)e^{-ikx}dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \bar {f}(x)e^{i(-k)x}dx=f(-k)$

I realise this is out by a $2\pi$ but you get the idea. (Your definition of a fourier transform needs a $2\pi $ somewhere).

Comment: I did the following:
$$F[\widetilde{f}(x)]=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{\widetilde{f}(x) e^{-ikx}}dx=2 \pi \frac{1}{2 \pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{\widetilde{f}(x) e^{ix(-k)}}dx=2 \pi f(-k)$$
But the property is: $F[\widetilde{f}(x)]=\frac{f(-k)}{2 \pi}$.. What have I done wrong??

Comment: The proper fourier transform is $F(f)=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)e^{-i kx}dx $

Comment: But in my notes there are the following formulas:
$$\text{Inverse Fourier Transform: }f(x)=\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{\widetilde{f}(k) e^{ikx}}dx$$
$$\text{Fourier Transform: }\widetilde{f}(k)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{f(x) e^{-ikx}}dx$$
Using these formulas, how can I prove the property?

Comment: Interesting,  the apperances of $\pi $ seem to change in fourier transforms, ive also seen them in the exponential,  but I would stick with your notes.

Comment: But the two formulas you have been given seem quite inconsistent.

Comment: What do you mean??

Comment: Well normally if there is a "$2\pi$" in one then there should be a "$2\pi $" in the other.